# How to add a project to source control (existing GIT remote repo) in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a solution (solution 1) that contains a project (project 1). This project was added to source control and I do all git operations normally. I had another solution with another project (project 2) that had a different repo.

I want to merge these 2 solutions and put them under 1 solution only. So, I right clicked on my solution in solution 1 and added existing project (project 2) to it. My problem is that the git repo on azure devops can't see that I added this project to the solution so basically I can't commit or revert or do any git operation. How can I fix that? I need to add this project to source control but when I right click it, add to source control is not there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Git operates on a directory structure. If all you did was add project2 to solution1, project2 is still not in solution1's directory structure. You'll have to move/copy project2 to the directory where solution1 and project1 are.

Comment: I think you don't really understand how GIT works (and that's ok, we have all been there).
Try to learn GIT commands instead of using the Visual Studio interface, everything will become crystal clear...

Answer (score 2):

Think of a local git repo as encompassing a parent folder. It includes all the (tracked) files in that folder or sub-folders.

In your Solution, there can be references that point to other folders, outside of that git repo. In fact, project/solution 2 already has a separate git repo, so that tells me it is in a different folder.

You have a few ways of resolving this, but to start with, you mostly likely want to remove project 2 from solution 1 to start with. Then decide how you want to add project 2 to solution 1.

---

### Just leave them separate repos!

The easiest response is actually just to leave them separate repos. You can change them independently, and update them in their own repos - however, as you have noticed, there are likely some problems with this if you are using VS's native git interface - I think you would have to swap between solutions.

The big downside of this is that git won't track which version of project 2 is being used at any given commit of solution 1 automatically. You would need a version explicitly indicated somewhere (I think it probably is somewhere in the solution config though?). I wouldn't rely on the solution configuration to track the underlying versioning for you - much better to have it all solidly tracked directly by git. From a version control system perspective, the other solutions are better.

---

### Just copy the folder over

The simplest solution that manages project 2 versioning is to just copy the project 2 folder from it's own folder / git repo into the folder / git repo for solution 1. First remove it from your solution, then copy it over, and readd project 2 from the new location.

After doing this, you can add it as a new project in solution 1, and all the links to it will be to this local copy.

However, the downside is that now solution 1/project 2 and the original project 2 in its separate repo are diverging. If project 2 is intended only for solution 1 at this point, that's probably fine.

---

### Make project 2 a submodule

The slightly more complex solution is to make the repo for project 2 a submodule of the repo for solution 1. This adds it as a folder within your solution 1 folder hierarchy, so it looks just like the prior solution, but there is a little extra work to understand how to update the submodule.

Basically, under this setup, the separate git repo is added with a reference to the correct commit in that repo to use at any given time. You can update repo 2 completely separately, or can change it directly in the submodule, make new commits, etc., but they are separate repos, with git keeping track of which version of repo 2 (which commit) is being used at all times, so the version control is automatic.

Last time I used Visual Studio, I do not believe it's native git interface had support for sub-modules. I'm not sure if it does now. You may need to learn how to manage them at the command line or with a separate visual GUI Git tool, like [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) (on Windows only, for v3+).